# Wordpress adding article category and tags via email post(s)

Tags: php, email, wordpress

I'm trying to add categories and tags to my posts. How can I achieve that if I am posting by email?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email#Hack_E-mail_Format

Also this QA could be considered as *Not Programming Related!* if you're not gonna fork [`wp-mail.php`](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress/trunk/wp-mail.php) to provide yourself with a specific format you like.
I believe that's a quite easy job, just parse your mail title or body for a special markup like for example: `##cat:5##` in the `for` statement *(line 47)* and assign that to your ongoing post.
As it seems, the feature is now implemented for the wordpress.com blogs using [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), according to [this page](http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-by-email/#shortcodes). Not sure if it's the same for a standalone installation but it worth a try, I think.